# Swift - Delegate is nil and error when trying to set it with segue

Tags: ios, swift

Ok, so basically I'm in the process of making a food diary app and I have protocol/delegate communication between a View Controller where the user enters a new food and a View Controller that shows an overview of all the food/meals.
My protocol and delegate code -

```
protocol NewEntryDelegate: class {
func getCalorieDataFromNewEntry(data: Int) 
}
-------
//NewEntryViewController
weak var delegate: NewEntryDelegate?
------
//OverviewViewController
func getCalorieDataFromNewEntry(data: Int) {

    totalCals += data
    defaults.set(totalCals, forKey: "totalCalories")

}
```

I have a property in the overview VC that stores the total amount of calories of food for the day and every time the user creates a new entry in the NewEntryVC, the calories for that entry should be sent back to the overview VC and added on to whatever the total currently is.
My code for this was previously working fine (NewEntryVC is embedded in a different nav controller as it's being presented modally and I want a nav bar)(condensed code)  -

```
class OverviewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,   
UITableViewDataSource, NewEntryDelegate {

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goToNewEntry" {

        let navController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let viewController = navController.topViewController as! NewEntryViewController
        viewController.delegate = self

    }
```

However, I have now added a new PopUpViewController in between the two View Controllers -
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVBTw.png)

And now I can't figure out how to reach the same instance of the NewEntryVC from the OverviewVC in order to set the delegate. I tried changing the code in my prepare(for segue:) method on OverviewController to `navController.topViewController.presentedViewController as! NewEntryViewController`

but that didn't work. I also tried making the NewEntryVC a child VC of the PopUpVC but that didn't work either. I also tried setting the delegate inside the PopUpVC class instead of OverviewVC class

```
class PopUpNewEntryViewController: UIViewController {

if segue.identifier == "goToNewEntry" {
        let destVC = segue.destination as! NewEntryViewController
        destVC.delegate = self.navigationController.presentingViewController as? NewEntryDelegate
```

but again no luck.

I've looked at all the similar posts on this but can't find a solution that fits my problem. Should I still be using protocol/delegate communication or would I be better off with Notification/Observer? If anyone can any suggestions it would be much appreciated! And if you need to see anymore of my code let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to just forward the delegate. popUpViewController.delegate = self and then destVC.delegate = delegate.

Comment: Yes that's it, thank you! Didn't realise it was so simple!